# Push notification Not receive

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am new in IOS Developing.and working on push notification.Firstly create all certificates example ssl and other push notification worked well. when testing for .IPA build for Device. The .IPA build installed on device using test flight with itunnes connect Push notification not received. But .IPA build installed using Diawi push notification received very well.To send .IPA file to itunnes connect firstly create Production certificate. But push notification not working. But is the Reason For This error.Thanks To advance.

Comment: Did you use two different certificates for sandbox (test) and production? I use Amazon SNS and sandbox-mode is used when I test locally and production-mode when I download the app from testflight.

Comment: when i use same certificate  to face same issue.than i create Production certificate

Comment: **Check** the certificate in code signing once again, to ensure you have used the correct certificate(**Production: Apple Push Notification service SSL**), and the pem file (**.p12**) created using **same certificate**.

Comment: my one question..same CSR file are using for production certificate? when i using for developmnet SSL Ceritificate?

Comment: This tutorial have a nice walkthrough, it may resolve your issue. https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: You can use same certificate and while creating provisioning profiles choose the same certificate for both development and distribution. No problem. But having different certificates and profiles were recommended.